# TextView on recyclerview item is not showing on the right place

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on a recyclerview view that looks as follows in Android Studio:

[image]

As you may see, there are two textViews, one with "Sample" text as one with "TextView" text.

I need to put the second textView just below the first textView, like it is in the image.

The eight circled ImageViews may appear or not, depending on the item values.

The issue is that the item on a real device looks different depending on the item values, if there are not ImageViews (the small grey circles) everything looks as I want,like this

[image]

but in case of existing circled ImageViews on the item, the second textView appears much lower, below the second circled ImageViews row, like this:

[image]

This is my code for the view:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"

            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_24dp"
            card_view:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
            card_view:civ_border_width="2dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/profile_image"
            android:text="Sample"
            android:textColor="@color/grey_700"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtUsername"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/txtUsername"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/profile_image"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_deportes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/txtUsername"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tres"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp1"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/skate" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp2"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/skate" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp3"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/skate" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp4"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/skate" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_deportes2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/layout_deportes"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tres"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp5"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/skate" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp6"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/layout_deportes"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/skate" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp7"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/skate" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp8"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/skate" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

I guess something must be wrong on it, but I am not able to find out the reason for the issue.

Comment: remove the alignStart and than try

Comment: @Amitpandey, I am trying your proposal, let me check it

Comment: @Amitpandey, done but no changes in the issue

Comment: Try add `android:layout_below="@id/txtUsername"` for the TextView with date

Comment: @S-Sh, it is already there

Comment: RelativeLayout tag is not closed

Comment: @maxwellnewage, it is closed, but not on the code shown in the question, there are more elements on the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Check this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@color/white_font"
        android:src="@drawable/img_card"
        card_view:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
        card_view:civ_border_width="2dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/rlImages"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/profile_image"
        android:text="Sample"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_font"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtUsername"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/txtUsername"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/rlImages"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/profile_image"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlImages"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/txtUsername"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_deportes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp1"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_gradient"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/img_card" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp2"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_gradient"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/img_card" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp3"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_gradient"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/img_card" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp4"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_gradient"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/img_card" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_deportes2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/layout_deportes"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp5"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_gradient"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/img_card" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp6"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/layout_deportes"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_gradient"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/img_card" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp7"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_gradient"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/img_card" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp8"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_gradient"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/img_card" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what are the differences with my code? I want to learn. What was wrong?

Comment: please ignore the images i've added, i don't have images like that so i added mine.
Your both LinearLayout moved in RelativeLayout and TextView position is onRight of RelativeLayout //android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/rlImages"/ that's it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    app:civ_border_width="@dimen/dp_2"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_close_black" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/profile_image"
    android:text="Sample"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/txtUsername"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/profile_image"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="10sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_deportes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtUsername"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tres"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sp1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close_black"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
       />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sp2"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_close_screen"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sp3"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sp4"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_deportes2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/layout_deportes"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtUsername"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sp5"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sp6"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_deportes"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sp7"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sp8"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what are the differences with my code? I want to learn. What was wrong?

Comment: the icon when they apper its take the height and the date goes below of the the icon thats the reason your date going below, and i dont have these file so i delete the other staff make it as you code and custmize it with your reuirement

Comment: and where is the change?

Comment: i set both the liner layout right of the user name you can see it